# How to increase max_words in Word-cloud using python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, visualization, word-cloud

I am using the word cloud implementation using using [word cloud generator](https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud).

Here is the code I have written, which is similar to that of the example they provided.

```
from os import path
from scipy.misc import imread
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS


def grey_color_func(word, font_size, position, orientation, random_state=None, **kwargs):
    return "hsl(0, 0%%, %d%%)" % random.randint(60, 100)

d = path.dirname(__file__)


with open("sample.csv") as f:
    lines = f.readlines() 
text = "".join(lines)
f.close()

stopwords = STOPWORDS.copy()



wc = WordCloud(max_words=15156633, stopwords=stopwords, margin=10,random_state=1).generate(text)
# generate_from_frequencies()
default_colors = wc.to_array()
plt.title("Custom colors")
plt.imshow(wc.recolor(color_func=grey_color_func, random_state=3))
wc.to_file("wordcloud_figure.png")
plt.axis("off")
plt.figure()
plt.title("Default colors")
plt.imshow(default_colors)
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

And the output I got is as follows:

[image: Word cloud generated]

Irrespective of the "max_words" (whether I increase or decrease) of the `WordCloud()` function, I am seeing almost no effect on the final putput.

What could be wrong?

Also, how to use the `generate_from_frequencies()` method which is mentioned in the [API reference](http://amueller.github.io/word_cloud/generated/wordcloud.WordCloud.html#wordcloud.WordCloud.generate_from_frequencies).

Answer (score 1):

The reason you don't see more words is that they are too small.
Which version of the wordcloud module are you using? In the git version, by default (`relative_scaling=0`), each word should decrease font size only if it doesn't fit any more.

Comment: Please to meet you sir. I just downloaded from the Github, not sure about the version. Any means to circumvent this? colored figure using to_file() method without using any masking pictures?

Comment: this seems odd. Can you open an issue on the wordcloud github and provide the input text? https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud/issues
Not sure when I'll have time to look into it, though.